How do I call MS Graph API from the server app in a Blazor WASM Hosted solution, using the Access Token from the client app?
The client FE app (Blazor WASM) signs in the user and then passes the access token along to the server BE app (ASP.NET Core Web API). Now, I'd like to somehow add the Graph client to the DI container in the server app and make calls to Graph API from services and controllers there. How do I do that?
Client app configuration
Client - Program.cs
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions);
});

builder.Services
    .AddHttpClient(HttpClients.SERVER_API, client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(appSettings.ServerApi.Url);
    })
    // This configues the client to add the JWT to the 'Authorization' header
    // for every request made to the authorized URLs.
    .AddHttpMessageHandler(sp =>
        sp.GetRequiredService<AuthorizationMessageHandler>()
            .ConfigureHandler(
                authorizedUrls: [ appSettings.ServerApi.Url ],
                scopes: [ appSettings.ServerApi.AccessScope ]
            ));

Client - appsettings.json
"AzureAd": {
    "Authentication": {
        "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/my-authority-here",
        "ClientId": "client-id-here"
    },
    "DefaultAccessTokenScopes": [
        "api://server-app-id-here/API.Access",
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read"
    ]
}

Server app configuration
Server - Program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(builder.Configuration)
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApis:MicrosoftGraph"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

Server - appsettings.json
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "myusername.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "my-tenant-id",
    "ClientId": "server-app-client-id",
    "ClientSecret": "server-app-secret",
    "Scopes": "API.Access",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
},
"DownstreamApis": {
    "MicrosoftGraph": {
        "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
        "Scopes": "User.Read"
    }
},

Server - Calling Graph
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

namespace ChatPortal.Server.Controllers;

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphClient;

    public TestController(GraphServiceClient graphClient)
    {
        _graphClient = graphClient;
    }

    [HttpGet("graph")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GraphTest()
    {
        var user = await _graphClient.Me.GetAsync();

        return Ok();
    }
}

Azure setup
Client app registration
API Permissions:

MyServerApp: API.Access, Type: Delegated, Status: Granted
Microsoft Graph: User.Read, Type: Delegated, Status: Granted

Server app registration
Expose an API:

Scopes: api://my-server-app-id-here/API.Access
Authorized client applications: my-client-app-id-here

The problem
If I remove the "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read" scope to DefaultAccessTokenScopes in the client's appsettings.json file I get this error when trying to call Graph:
[12:47:58 ERR] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityWebChallengeUserException: IDW10502: An MsalUiRequiredException was thrown due to a challenge for the user. See https://aka.ms/ms-id-web/ca_incremental-consent.
 ---> MSAL.NetCore.4.66.1.0.MsalUiRequiredException:
        ErrorCode: invalid_grant
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException: AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'my-id-here' named 'ChatPortal.Server'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.

I tried following the link the error provides for "managing incremental consent" and getting the token in the TestController through ITokenAcquisition but that seemingly tries to get the token from Azure. That doesn't seem correct for this scenario (and it doesn't work) -- I already have the access token in the Request.Headers.Authorization property. The question is how I use it with the GraphServiceClient...
If I keep the User.Read scope in the DefaultAccessTokenScopes this is the error I get:
Request URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/my-tentant-id-here/oauth2/v2.0/token
Invalid request: AADSTS28000: Provided value for the input parameter scope is not valid because it contains more than one resource. Scope api://server-app-id-here/API.Access https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read openid profile offline_access is not valid.


One access token contains only one aud you cannot call two different resources at once

May I know whether your API would work when you add [Authorize] attribute before public class TestController : ControllerBase{? You are working on on-behalf-of flow now,  and your codes looks good except the scopes just like what Rukmini said. But you already put "api://server-app-id-here/API.Access" before Graph API scope, so that the token should work as well. May I know, whether your access token could work when you create an API with [Authorize] attribute on the Controller and use the token to call that API? If not, I'm afraid there's some mistake in configuration.

In your API project,Graph SDK has to be authorized so that it could call Graph API. But it's an API project, so that it could only use on-behalf-of flow. Since you already integrated Azure AD to secure your API with builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(builder.Configuration).EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi().AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApis:MicrosoftGraph")).AddInMemoryTokenCaches(); so that whenever you are using the access token to call a secured API successfully, in that API GraphClient is authorized...My humble opinion.


Note that: You cannot pass two or more resources as scope to generate the token or in the request.

For sample, I tried to generate the token and passed scope as API and the Microsoft Graph API:
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id: ClientID
grant_type: authorization_code
scope: api://xxx/ScopeName https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read openid profile offline_access
redirect_uri: RedirectURL
code: code
client_secret: Secret


And got the same error:

The error "AADSTS28000: Provided value for the input parameter scope is not valid because it contains more than one resource. Scope api://xxx/claims.read https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read openid profile offline_access is not valid." usually occurs if you are passing two or more distinct resources as scope in the request.

One access token can contain only one aud , in your case one single token cannot call the API and the Microsoft Graph.
The aud claim in an access token is designated for the specific API or resource for which the token is created.

Hence to resolve the error, you need to make two different requests one to call the API and one more to call the Microsoft Graph API:
To call the API pass scope as api://xxx/ScopeName:

To call Microsoft Graph API, pass scope as https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read openid profile offline_access:


Thanks for your reply, I didn't know you that an access token couldn't have two aud. However, this doesn't really help me I'm afraid. My question is about how to setup the Graph client in my C# server app (a web API).
Maybe I'm misunderstanding the flow here, and I'm not supposed to use the user's access token from the frontend client at all?

Can you attach the GitHub repo so I can reproduce?

Unfortunately it's proprietary code, but I will try my best to create a minimal reproducing sample for you.

Okay sure:) please attach it

ANy update on the issue? @kglundgren
